# Update data in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have registration as my database table. I want to update my information that has key in by the user into my SQL Server database. But it won't work, it don't occur any errors but the data key in wouldn't update into my database. Someone please help me if anything wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=webservice_database;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE registration SET username = @username, password = @password, retypepassword = @retypepassword, gender = @gender, birth = @birth, address = @address, city = @city, country = @country, postcode = @postcode, email = @email, carno = @carno", con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@retypepassword", TextBoxRPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", DropDownListGender.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth", DropDownListDay.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBoxAddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBoxCity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownListCountry.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", TextBoxPostcode.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carno", TextBoxCarno.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Redirect("UpdateSuccess.aspx");
    }
```

After I click confirm it somehow only update my column `gender` which from male to female, others column of data it won't update.

Comment: What is the primary key in your table?
Can you add a try/catch and see if there is an exception?

Comment: How does the command look like when it is sent to the server? If you have the full version, then use the profiler to examine what is being sent to the server.

Comment: THat seems to make zero sense. Seriously. THere is no UPDATE ON USERNAME as you also have it in the where clause. Set name=a where name=a? Never update primary keys. Well, also give us the error message.

Comment: My program can update the information already. Because I found out in my page load I perform the read and get data from the database into the TextBox, after I command the read data at page load, my changes made can be update successfully.
But how would I do that I want the information to display in the TextBox in the initial state and made changes after that?

Comment: All control events will fire before the form_load event fire. So you should create a hiddenfield to hold the unique id. The update should be done in the click event and loading should be done in form_load when it is not a postback. If the hiddenfield is not set, this is a new entry. Create a unique id and do an INSERT. If hiddenfield is set, do an UPDATE.

Comment: Depending on the version of SQL Server you're using, you may also want to consider the MERGE statement, which handles the upsetting case for you in a single SQL block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because the @username is used both in UPDATE and WHERE. If it changes, the WHERE will be wrong and if it does not change it can be left out of the query.

Answer (score -1):

sql update

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update[Testing].[dbo].[student] set name= '" + tb1.Text + "',age='" + tb2.Text + "',mobile='" + tb3.Text+ "' where id = '" + tb4.Text + "'", con);

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=webservice_database;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE username = " + TextBoxUsername.Text + "UPDATE registration SET username = @username, password = @password, retypepassword = @retypepassword, gender = @gender, birth = @birth, address = @address, city = @city, country = @country, postcode = @postcode, email = @email, carno = @carno", con);

    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@retypepassword", TextBoxRPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", DropDownListGender.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth", DropDownListDay.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBoxAddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBoxCity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownListCountry.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", TextBoxPostcode.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carno", TextBoxCarno.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Redirect("UpdateSuccess.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Just posting the working code is not a very good answer, try explaining where the mistake was

Answer (score -3):

I think in page load you are load again all data and Button1_Click run after page load and you lost are all data
you can try your code in page_load method

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=webservice_database;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE registration SET username = @username, password = @password, retypepassword = @retypepassword, gender = @gender, birth = @birth, address = @address, city = @city, country = @country, postcode = @postcode, email = @email, carno = @carno " + "WHERE username = @username", con);

    con.Open();
.
.
.

    }
}
```

Comment: -1. Less thinking, more correct answers? The SQL is borked to start with.

Answer (score -4):

I have never seen that type of syntax.  Usually if one is using parameters, one is using a `stored proc` (the best practice).  If one is using `inline SQL`, one builds the `SQL` statement as a single text line and executes it.  I would recommend recoding for one of those.

If you want to try what you've started, in your `SQL`, you probably need to declare all the variables first.  For example

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("declare @username varchar(100), @password varchar(100), 
@retypepassword varchar(100) @gender varchar(10), @birth date, @address varchar(100), 
@city varchar(100) @country varchar(100), @postcode varchar(10), @email varchar(100), 
@carno varchar(100) UPDATE registration SET username = @username, password = @password, 
retypepassword = @retypepassword, gender = @gender, birth = @birth, address = @address, 
city = @city, country = @country, postcode = @postcode, email = @email, carno = @carno", 
con);
```

Comment: There's no requirement that days you can't use parameters with inline SQL text, and you definitely don't want to declare the variables like you did above when working inline.

Comment: Who, that is the most bloated way I have ever seen to issue an update statement.